# How to terminate session when the browser is closed in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

can somebody tell / show me how to terminate session in rails 3?

In my web app, if the user closed the browser and opened it again the the user is still logged in. How am I gonna make it automatically log out when the user closed the browser?

Pls help.

Comment: How are you logging the user in? Sessions are done when the browser is closed by default.

Comment: Change the session cookie from permanent to "session" (don't know how it's done in Ruby). That'll let the browser delete the cookie when it's closed, and the user will come back to a new/fresh session the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

or if you don't want to, then expire the session as describe in [Rails Security Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-expiry).

Comment: Thanks man, I'll try that. BTW, I'm not using Devise instead I created my own sign_in and sign_up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a comprehensive post about using session instead of cookies for login and logout:

http://www.nimweb.it/web-development/ruby-on-rails-web-development/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-exercise-9-6-2-rails-session/

This is also the answer to Michael Hartl's Exercise 2 in Chapter 9 (9.6.2), in his Rails Tutorial,  which I highly recommend if you're learning Rails: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Comment: Link appears to be broken.